# Trying to add an additional value to an existing value in a column for all the rows that are retrieved using a stored procedure for

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have spent quite a long time to figure out.. so my update statement is affecting 0 rows although I know for a fact that it should affect at least affect more than a few rows as I have tried as a standalone. In place of update statement I tried select statement and it is working so does that mean that update statement is not supposed to work in stored procedure.. I kinda doubt it.. so I would like to get a second opinion.

```
my stored procedure code here: 
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE updateKeywordsInRIConsole(in retailerId int )

BEGIN

declare key_words varchar(200) default null;

declare grpid bigint(20);

declare finished bool default false;

declare cur1 cursor for 
    select Keywords, GRPID  
    from RIConsole 
    where RetailerID = retailerId 
    and  DateCreated > date(now()) - interval 1 year 
    and INSTR(Keywords, "offer_page") = false;

declare continue handler for not found set finished = 1;


declare exit handler for sqlexception
begin
        show errors;
end;

declare exit handler for sqlwarning
begin
        show warnings;
end;

open cur1;

    start_loop: loop

        fetch cur1 into key_words, grpid;

        if finished = 1 then 

            leave start_loop;

        end if;

      update RIConsole set Keywords = concat(key_words, " ", 
      "offer_page") where GRPID = cast(grpid as signed); <-- this code not working...I called it with cast function to make sure.. and i also tried without it. 




    end loop start_loop;

close cur1;


END $$

DELIMITER ;

DROP PROCEDURE updateKeywordsInRIConsole;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do an UPDATE in a stored procedure.

If you are happy with your SELECT, you could do the while thing in a single statement. e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateKeywordsInRIConsole(IN retailerId INT)

BEGIN
  UPDATE  RIConsole 
  SET Keywords = CONCAT(Keywords, " ",  "offer_page") 
  WHERE where RetailerID = retailerId 
  AND DateCreated > DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
  AND INSTR(Keywords, "offer_page") = false;
END 
;
```